# How to retrieve object properties from a class expression defined in the "Equivalent To" section of an owl class in Java?

Tags: java, protege, owl-api

I have defined (in Protege) a class Missing which is equivalent to ((not (atHome value 30)) and (not (atWork value 30)))and (not (onleave value 30)).
By using OWL-API, I would like to **obtain the single object properties** (in this case, the negated object properties) **from the class expression**, in order to further get their domains and ranges and perform further reasoning. However, I am not sure how to parse the whole equivalent class expression in Java.

For now I am able to retrieve the equivalent class expression of a class (in this case Missing) in functional form with the following code.

```
localOntology.getEquivalentClassesAxioms(missingClass);
```

The provided code returns the functional representation of the equivalence class expression I have provided in Protege, however I am not able to parse it and retrive not (atWork value 30), not (atHome value 30), not (onleave value 30), which is what I would like.

Answer (score 1):

- First. In the described above ontology IRIs `atHome`, `atWork` and `onleave` are not object properties, but rather data properties, since `atHome value 30` is a [Literal Value Restriction](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-syntax/#Literal_Value_Restriction), that has datatype property, not object property. If, of course, it is not [Punning](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl2-new-features/#F12:_Punning).
- In OWL-API v5, the method `OWLOntology#getEquivalentClassesAxioms(OWLClass)` is deprecated. Instead it is recommended to use its Java-Stream-API companion: `OWLOntology#equivalentClassesAxioms(OWLClass)`
- Using this method the solution (getting all data properties for the specified OWL Class) might look like this:

  `o.equivalentClassesAxioms(c)
                      .flatMap(OWLNaryClassAxiom::operands)
                      .filter(x -> x instanceof OWLObjectComplementOf)
                      .map(x -> ((OWLObjectComplementOf) x).getOperand())
                      .filter(x -> x instanceof OWLDataHasValue)
                      .flatMap(x -> ((OWLDataHasValue) x).components())
                      .filter(x -> x instanceof OWLDataProperty)
                      .forEach(System.out::println);`
- the same can be rewritten using the standard Java Collections API, but more cumbersome.
- Also, it is possible to use `org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.OWLObjectComponentCollector` or `org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.OWLEntityCollector` utility tools, but theses particular impls collect all components in a single `Set`, so it is still need to filter the result:

  `o.equivalentClassesAxioms(c)
                  .flatMap(a -> new OWLObjectComponentCollector().getComponents(a)
                          .stream().filter(x -> x instanceof OWLDataProperty))
                  .forEach(System.out::println)`;
- create your own `org.semanticweb.owlapi.util.AbstractCollectorEx` impl to collect only data properties.